# cannot find the Glew Frameworks

Tags: opengl, glew

iam a mac user and my mac running on os x mountain lion 10.8.3 and my xcode version is 4.6.2. My question is, where i can find the glew.frameworks and angel.h ? because i have search on my library frameworks and there's nothing.

Comment: Is this to compile the code from "Interactive Computer Graphics" by Edward Angel?

Comment: GLEW is not a framework that comes with xcode. You need to download it from http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The **angel.h** header file is available from [Edward Angel's book website](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION) (6<sup>th</sup> edition); here's a [direct link](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/include/Angel.h) to the file.  That site also includes instructions for compling the programs on the most popular operating systems, including Mac OS X.

As for GLEW, you really don't need it on Mac OS X.  Since it seems the GLEW code isn't properly `#ifdef` guarded in those examples, you can just remove the call to `glewInit()`, and recompile.

Speaking of compiling, you if you're using the command line, you just need to add the appropriate frameworks for the code:

```
g++ ... -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL
```

Comment: so the angel.h is associated with math.h,vec.h, and checkerror.h. and there are 3 problems with math.h that can't be compiled, return mat2(); and the error is Non-const lvalue reference to type 'Angel::mat2 cannot bind to temporary of type'Angel::mat2'.